# Why some tables in popular databases dont have primary keys defined?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, tfs, primary-key

I have seen tables in some databases (e.g. SAP, TFS, both configuration and collection) that don't have primary keys defined. Why is that?

Comment: The question seems more related to the database structure of sql server, not to TFS itself.

Comment: Is it a general SQL or database-agnostic question? SAP is a huge software company, which proposes many database software, software delivered with tables (all the ones I know have tables with a primary key), etc.

Answer (score 2):

In TFS a number of tables don't have a primary key nor foreign keys due very specific to performance constraints. Plus, these databases are not supposed to be updated manually, TFS handles all changes to these tables though its own APIs. It's one of the reasons why Microsoft doesn't support direct querying against these tables.

Another reason in the case of TFS is that its cloud counterpart, Visual Studio Team Services, doesn't store all of its data in SQL Azure, but in Table Storage Blob storage or DocumentDB.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has attempted an answer to this yet, so here goes...

Some tables don't need a PRIMARY KEY, because they are never going to be updated, and might only have a tiny set of data in them (e.g. lookup tables).  If these tables have no indexes at all then they are essentially heaps, which isn't always a bad thing.

Why should every table have a PRIMARY KEY defined anyway?  If the table has a UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX in place then this does just about everything that a PRIMARY KEY does, with the added bonus that you can allow NULL values to be stored.  Depending on the implementation (e.g. SQL Server allows only one "unique" NULL value, other RDBMs allow multiple) this might be a much better match to your application.

For example, let's say you want a table with two columns, account number and account name.  Let's assume that you make your PRIMARY KEY account number, because you want to ensure it is unique.  Now you want to allow NULL account numbers, because these aren't always supplied at the point where you create an account; you have some weird 2-part process where you create a record with just a name, then backfill the account number.  If you stick to the PRIMARY KEY design then you would need to do something like add an IDENTITY column, make this the PRIMARY KEY, then add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to prevent identical multiple account numbers.

Now you are left with a surrogate key that is going to be of little use to any queries, so you would probably end up with a performance index anyway, even if you don't care about uniqueness.

If you had no PRIMARY KEY, but instead a UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX then you would be able to do this without changing your table, with only one customer ever allowed to have a NULL account number at the same time (if it's SQL Server).

I designed a database for a customer a couple of years ago that had over 200 tables, and not a single PRIMARY KEY.  Although this was more about me "making a point", it's not a stretch to assume that the same is true for other database developers out there.